# Override/Rewrite a javascript library function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am using an open source javascript library [timeline.verite.co](http://timeline.verite.co) 
It's a timeline library which works great on page load. But when I try to repaint the timeline on certain condition, it starts giving out weird errors

I would like to modify the init function in the library. But instead of changing it in the original library itself, I would like to rewrite/override this function in another separate .js file so that when this function is called, instead of going to the original function, it must use my modified function.

I'm not sure whether to use prototype/ inheritance and how to use it to solve this problem?

Comment: What library are you using?  What function in said library are you trying to override?  Depending on how that function is declared, the method is different.

Comment: It really depends on the library, can you provide a link? (Thanks for converting this to a comment!)

Comment: There is a link on this page, to download the library. 

http://timeline.verite.co/
Its a timeline library which works great on page load. But when I try to repaint the timeline on certain condition, it starts giving out weird errors.

Comment: I'm not sure how to recall the init function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to assign the new value for it. Here is an example:

```
obj = {
        myFunction : function() {
            alert('originalValue');
        }
    }

    obj.myFunction();
    obj.myFunction = function() {
        alert('newValue');
    }
    obj.myFunction();
```