# how to extend a javascript library?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am new to programming and I want to know if I can expand a library of javascript and override methods?

Suppose we have installed library dropzone. we can extend it and override methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override/Rewrite a javascript library function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099471/override-rewrite-a-javascript-library-function)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I do normally change the functions in the library itself. This does of course only work if you have installed the library locally and you do want to have the method changed in all your code.

If you still need to access the original function, or other people will also read your code, then take a look at this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099471/override-rewrite-a-javascript-library-function).

Comment: it is ok to change position in the local library?As extends exactly? can you give me an example?

Comment: As I said it is not the common way, but it is easy and when nobody else will read your code, I do not see any reason why you should do it another way..